# Select entire file in Vim, without the last new line character

Tags: vim

Assume I open this file in Vim:

```
111
222
333
```

This file has 3 lines. I want to copy and paste the entire file to another text editor.

I ran

`ggVG`

to select entire file. Then copy the text. And I past the file in another editor (Notepad).

In 2nd editor, what gets pasted is

```
111
222
333
```

It has an extra new line (4th line).

Is there a command which allows me to select entire file in Vim, without the last new line character?

Comment: Could it be the empty line was already present in your other editor before pasting anything?

Comment: Before pasting into the new buffer, replace the already existing line with `V`, so type `Vp`.

Comment: ggVG  selects line by line. So new line char is by default included. My questions: is a command to select the enter file without the last new line?

Comment: One of `gg0vG$` and `gg0vG$h` should do that.

Comment: @JG1980 If you don't want to select the last newline, you can not use the linewise visual mode (`V`): Do `ggvG$` instead.

Comment: Easy: open the file in Notepad directly.

Answer (score 2):

`ggVG` explicitly uses visual-line mode so it includes all newlines, including the last one. If you don't want the visually selected text to contain that last newline, all you have to do is use regular visual mode:

```
gg0vG$
```

where:

- `gg` moves the cursor to line 1,
- `0` moves the cursor to column 1,
- `v` enters visual mode,
- `G` extends visual selection to last line,
- `$` extends visual selection to last character.

At this point, pressing `y` should yank the visual selection, excluding the last newline.

But, IMO, a better strategy would be to keep yanking how you are used to in Vim and select the line in the target editor before pasting whatever you got from Vim:

- `Shift+Right` or whatever to select the empty line,
- `Ctrl+V` or whatever to paste the content of the clipboard.

FWIW, `ggyG` is shorter and more direct (no intermediary visual step) than `ggVGy`, and so is `:%y<CR>`.

Opening the source file in the target editor is still the best approach, IMO.

Comment: One could also paste with *Ctrl+V* followed by *Backspace* to immediately remove the offending line break.

Comment: In visual mode, `$` should appear one character after the last character of the line, thus included the newline that is the actual end of the line. I could be wrong but I think you might need `gg0vG$hy`.

Answer (score 1):

```
111
222
333
```

You move the cursor to the last number/letter/character or whatever:
For example, here, if you move the cursor from the first number on the left, i.e. 1, to the last number on the right, i.e. 3, and press `y`, your desired part will be completely copied.
But note that to paste it, if you need the entire line (that is, exactly 3 lines to be copied), you need to press the `Y` key.